# Qt tag badge missing

Tags: feature-request, badges

There is a plethora of tag badges, but why isn't there a Qt tag badge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These badges are automatically created. No one ever reached 400 upvodes on the `qt` tag, not even close - the top user has 213 upvotes at the moment: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/qt/stats